# Trying to integrate Corda R3 blockchain with an Utimaco HSM using the SunPKCS11 provider

Tags: blockchain, corda, pkcs#11, hsm

Corda R3 has documentation for using the CryptoServer JCE provider, but I have found the SunPKCS11 provider wrapped over the Utimaco pkcs11 provider appears to work better. I have not been able to determine what needs to be added to the node.conf file. Any insight on this appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the PKCS#11 provider is supported for Corda currently. Only the CryptoServer JCE provider has been tested and is supported.

Did you try following the documentation below ?

https://docs.corda.r3.com/cryptoservice-configuration.html#id1

The node configuration described in this document should be sufficient to configure a Corda ENT node to use a Utimaco HSM.

Comment: Yes I have used the Utimaco JCE provider. Just trying to determine if it would work with the Utimaco PKCS#11 provider as it appears to be better supported by Utimaco. Appreciate your input. This may be why I am not being successful.

Comment: Yes, I would say it's wise to assume that whatever is not advertised as supported in the public documentation has not been tested and might not work at all.

Comment: The Sun JCE provider is based on PKCS#11, underneath.  To the Java application, it looks like JCE (because it is), but internally it is using PKCS#11 to talk to a P11 backend (HSM, etc).  That's how jarsigner (for example) can use a P11 backend.